# How to check in JS if p:calendar value is empty?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I got such kind of problem - I need to check in my JSF/PrimeFaces page if `p:calendar` value (entered by user with keyboard) is empty and if it so to clear error message

this is my JSF Calendar snippet

```
 <div class="item">
    <p:outputLabel id="l_dateBirth" for="dateBirth" value="#{msgs['customerForm.dateBirth']}"/>
    <p:calendar id="dateBirth" widgetVar="dateBirthVar" value="#{customerBean.customer.dateOfBirth}"
                placeholder="MM/dd/yyyy"
                showOn="button" navigator="true"
                pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" yearRange="-120:+0"
                mindate="#{dateBean.minDate}" 
                maxdate="#{dateBean.maxDateOfBirth}"
                required="true" 
                requiredMessage="#{msgs['Error.dateBirth.mandatory']}"
                disabled="#{customerBean.mode eq 'EDIT'}">
                <f:ajax execute="@this" event="dateSelect" render="m_dateBirth" />
                <p:ajax event="keyup" oncomplete="hideCustomerCalendarErrMsg('dateBirth')" />
                <f:validator binding="#{dateOfBirthValidator}"/>
                </p:calendar><p:message id="m_dateBirth" for="dateBirth" display="text"/>
</div>
```

this is my JS snippet

```
function hideCustomerCalendarErrMsg(variable) {
    var inputField, msg;
    inputField = PF('dateBirthVar').getDate();
    msg = document.getElementById("createEditCustomerForm:accordion:m_" +variable);
    if (inputField.value === null) {
        msg.innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

so, please help me - it doesnt work. And I need to clear validator err message on the fly if user clear the field of calendar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling getDate(), try to check the input itself for empty value.

```
function hideCustomerCalendarErrMsg(variable) {
   var inputField, msg;
   inputField = PF('dateBirthVar').input;
   msg = document.getElementById("createEditCustomerForm:accordion:m_" + variable);
   if (inputField.val() === "") {
       msg.innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

---

Or you can still have your code as it is, but instead of

```
if (inputField.value === null)
```

Go for

```
if (inputField === null)
```

Comment: I did it( but it is also dont work - function hideCustomerCalendarErrMsg(variable) {
    var inputField, msg;
    inputField = PF('dateBirthVar').input;
    msg = document.getElementById("createEditCustomerForm:accordion:m_dateBirth");
    if (inputField.value === null) {
        msg.innerHTML = "";}}

Comment: yes because you still have `if (inputField.value === null) ` replace it with `if (inputField.val() === "")` @DmitriyLaletin

Comment: I do as you said - function hideCustomerCalendarErrMsg(variable) {
    var inputField, msg;
    inputField = PF('dateBirthVar').input;
    msg = document.getElementById("createEditCustomerForm:accordion:m_dateBirth");
    if (inputField.val === "") {
        msg.innerHTML = "";}}

Comment: but it is still dont works( I spend the whole night on this bug(( can I ask you for a favor - is it possible to show you my code and result by skype - dima.laletin  I will be very gratefull if you will find few minutes

Comment: btw have a look at this article, can help you a lot in dealing with widgetVar http://blog.hatemalimam.com/intro-to-primefaces-widgetvar/